# Python in Excel FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have book1.xlsx and online_retail.xlsx in the same folder.
Tried to load the Excel file into DataFrame using Pandas however it returned an error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'online_retail.xlsx'`.

How to set Python in Excel current folder?

Tried

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('online_retail.xlsx')
```

Got

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'online_retail.xlsx'
```

Tried

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Dev\Python\online_retail.xlsx')
```

Got

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '"C:\\Dev\\Python\\online_retail.xlsx"'
```

Tried

```
import os
current_working_directory = os.getcwd()
print(current_working_directory)
```

Got

```
/app
```

Tried

```
import os
os.chdir("C:\Dev\Python")
```

Got

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Dev\\Python'
<br>
```

Comment: is your python file present in the same directory with xlsx files?
os.getcwd() is returning the "/app". Try moving your python file to same folder as xlsx files

Answer (score 0):

I found it's security features, not a bug
I should import data instead